# Error: Request cancelled while waiting for connection while pulling Docker images

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, repository, docker-registry

I am trying to pull images from dockerhub. I am using oracle linux machine. I have all the required packages installed to get docker running.

```
(venv-c3dns) root@localhost:~# yum list installed | grep docker
containerd.io.x86_64                     1.6.24-3.1.el8                               @docker-ce-stable
docker-buildx-plugin.x86_64              0.11.2-1.el8                                 @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64                         3:24.0.7-1.el8                               @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce-cli.x86_64                     1:24.0.7-1.el8                               @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce-rootless-extras.x86_64         24.0.7-1.el8                                 @docker-ce-stable
docker-compose-plugin.x86_64             2.21.0-1.el8                                 @docker-ce-stable
```

Also, I have proxies added in profiles.d/proxy.sh

```
(venv-c3dns) root@localhost:~# cat /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
export https_proxy=http://101.515.219.151:8080
export http_proxy=http://101.515.219.151:8080
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1"
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://10.515.219.151:8080
export HTTP_PROXY=http://101.515.219.151:8080
export NO_PROXY="127.0.0.1"
```

Also added the same in /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service under services.

After that when I try to do a docker pull, I am getting

```
(venv-c3dns) root@localhost:~# docker pull busybox
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Any help would be appreciated